# Online Multipler Games in Java

Tags: java, server, client, client-server

In Java, is there a way to make a client/server system for a game without having to enter ips (like in Minecraft). 
But instead, have it automatically connect the user to a game when he requests to join one (like in Fortnite, or [surviv.io](http://surviv.io/)).

The only method I current know for client/server is having to give each user a server ip to connect to (like in Minecraft), so I was wondering if I could do it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, even in the case of Fortnite, the user is connected to fortnite game server when you log in/start the game. It's just happened to be hidden from we users.

Comment: Yeah but how do I do that?
How do I make it automatically connect like that without the user having to enter an ip address themselves?

Comment: Typically, 1. You write your server code 2. Deploy it to cloud providers such as AWS. 3. Register the domain  4. Map the server IP with the domain. 5. Create a client app that internally hits the domain you registered for all the data you need. 6. That's all. This way user of the client app doesn't have to enter any IP or connect to any one explicitly. Your client app will do that for users.

Comment: Think of it like how twitter app is able to get all your feed to your mobile app w/o having you to enter twitter url

Comment: Could you maybe find or send a tutorial on how this is done? And do cloud providers usually cost money? If they do, are there any good free ones?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I think in all ".io" games, they are only hiding the registration processing. In my case, the previous game I made had a feature calls "Quick Play".
When a player uses that playing method and first time joins the game, I get his device's ID (for example in Android) then use it as a unique ID for that player in-game (I'm not sure about iOS but you can get that unique value in Android).
You can see the example below:

```
_on(TEvent.CONNECTION_SUCCESS, args -> {
            var connection = Connection.convert(args[0]);
            var message = TObject.convert(args[1]);

            info("CONNECTION", connection.getAddress());

            // Allow the connection login into server (become a player)
            String username = message.getString("u");
            // Should confirm that credentials by data from database or other services, here
            // is only for testing
            _playerApi.login(new PlayerLogin(username), connection);

            return null;
});
```

Now when a new user login, he will send his device's ID and I can treat him a new player and make that ID as his name (or making a randomized name for him)

You can see more detail in the link below:
[Login Example](https://github.com/congcoi123/tenio/blob/master/tenio-examples/src/main/java/com/tenio/examples/example1/TestServerLogin.java)